# receiving "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error while using dataclasses(OOP) while I don't face any error coding procedura

Tags: python, oop, web-scraping

Im receiving "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" while trying to code base on OOP while I don't face this error when Im not using 'Class' and coding procedura. the the error highlights **get_price_information(self.ticker, self.currency)** and **price = float(price_div['data-last-price'])**

my procedura code(which doesn't return any error):

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dataclasses import dataclass



def get_fx_to_usd(currency):
    fx_url = f'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{currency}-USD'
    resp = r.get(fx_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    fx_rate = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-last-price' : True})
    fx = float(fx_rate['data-last-price'])

    return fx



def get_price_information(ticker, exchange):
    url = f'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticker}:{exchange}'
    resp = r.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    price_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-last-price' : True}) 
    price = float(price_div['data-last-price'])
    currency = price_div['data-currency-code']

    usd_price = price
    if currency != 'USD':
        fx = get_fx_to_usd(currency)
        usd_price = round(price * fx, 2)
    else:
        usd_price = 'Same Price as USD!'

    
    return {
        'ticker' : ticker,
        'exchange': exchange,
        'price' : price, 
        'currency' : currency,
        'usd_price' : usd_price
    }
```

and this is my OOP code which returns the error:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Stock:
    ticker = str
    exchange = str
    price = float = 0
    currency = str = 'USD'
    usd_price = float = 0

    def __init__(self, ticker, exchange):
        price_info = get_price_information(self.ticker, self.exchange)

        if price_info['ticker'] == self.ticker:
            self.price = price_info['price']
            self.currency = price_info['currency']       
            self.usd_price = price_info['usd_price']



def get_fx_to_usd(currency):
    fx_url = f'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{currency}-USD'
    resp = r.get(fx_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    fx_rate = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-last-price' : True})
    fx = float(fx_rate['data-last-price'])

    return fx



def get_price_information(ticker, exchange):
    url = f'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticker}:{exchange}'
    resp = r.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    price_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-last-price' : True}) 
    price = float(price_div['data-last-price'])
    currency = price_div['data-currency-code']

    usd_price = price
    if currency != 'USD':
        fx = get_fx_to_usd(currency)
        usd_price = round(price * fx, 2)
    else:
        usd_price = 'Same Price as USD!'

    
    return {
        'ticker' : ticker,
        'exchange': exchange,
        'price' : price, 
        'currency' : currency,
        'usd_price' : usd_price
    }



print(Stock('SHOP', 'TSE'))
```

Comment: If you really think this isn't a duplicate, please [edit] to provide debugging details and explain why the duplicate doesn't cover your problem.

Comment: @tripleee my main problem isn't about the BeautifulSoup. the code works well but when I try to use dataclasses, it returns the problem. I explained it clearly as I could. I just wanted to know my problem is about the __init__ or else?

Comment: You never copy `self.ticker` and `self.exchange` from the keyword arguments in `__init__` so they are unset.

Comment: @tripleee ummm... sorry but I don't understand what exactly you mean?(also thanks for your consideration!)

Comment: You need to explicitly set `self.ticker = ticker` and similarly for `exchange`; the method's keyword arguments are entirely distinct from the object's attributes and there is no mechanism to automatically copy them over; your `__init__` method needs to do this if that's the behavior you require.

Comment: I added a second duplicate which addresses this in more detail.